# how to make comma separated list into proper CSV format

Tags: notepad++, regex, csv

I have a comma separated list of email adresses for example
"friend1@example.xyz, friend2@example.xyz, friend3@example.xyz"

But I would need to convert it to proper CSV format.
So replacing the spaces, I assume.

But how can this be done?
Do I need to use 'search and replace' with regex commands? And if so, how to?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] and supply before and after example text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file contains no other space characters than the ones after the commas, there's no real need for regex in search and replace.
You can just open the *Replace...* dialog and enter a space character in the *Find what:* box and make sure there's nothing in the *Replace with:* box.

Make sure to rename the file to .csv as well if it is not already. 
If you have *Hide extensions for known file types* enabled (Default) in Windows Explorer you will need to either re-save the file with the new file extension; disable the Windows Explorer setting or rename the file via the command line.

Comment: thank you!, 
I thought I needed regex, but it works also without :)

Answer (score 3):

The CSV file format is not fully standardized even there exist [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)
(this standard only specifies handling of text-based fields).

[RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) requirements:

- MS-DOS-style lines that end with (CR/LF) characters (optional for the
  last line).
- An optional header record (there is no sure way to detect whether it
  is present, so care is required when importing).
- Each record "should" contain the same number of comma-separated
  fields.
- Any field may be quoted (with double quotes).
- Fields containing a line-break, double-quote, and/or commas should be
  quoted. (If they are not, the file will likely be impossible to
  process correctly).
- A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two
  (double) quote characters.

Back to your question:

> I have a comma separated list of email addresses for example
> `friend1@example.xyz, friend2@example.xyz, friend3@example.xyz`

> But I would need to convert it to proper CSV format. So replacing the
> spaces, I assume

To remove spaces:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
- In the field `Find what` type `[ \t]+`
- The field `Replace with`should be empty.
- In the `Search mode` section switch radio button to `regular expression`
  and hit button <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

When you cleared text from spaces, you may want to enclose column data in quotes:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
- In the field `Find what` type `([^,\r\n]+)`
- In the field `Replace with`type `\"\1\"`
- In the `Search mode` section switch radio button to `regular expression`
  and hit button <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

**Note:** this (surrounding data in quotes) applies to the text saved in DOS/Windows format, if you processing data from Linux, then remove `\r` form `Find what` field.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it works (also without regex) :)

Comment: @mravec It depend on CSV reader, if it would be default settings in Excel or LibreOffice, they would pick column data with spaces